# Using VSCode with PHP (7) Debugger in Ubuntu

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode in Ubuntu to work with a php project. I was working great with the php debugger extension (and xdebug), but now it suddenly stop working. (No updates, no change in config. Just a simple restart computer). Exact problem is that VSCode won't stop on breakpoints in the code.

Netbeans works great with xdebug, so i don't know what can cause this issue with VSCode.

Any tips or ideas i should try?

Thanks in advance.

I have already changed the port where xdebug was running, try differents launch.json from the Internet, but no idea whats going on. I recently have activated the log option and i have some output from vscode, about a "malformed HTTP Request", I guess that's a clue.

Here is my launch.json file with the config I have set. (xdebug is on port 9090 in the php.ini file)

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9090,
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/site/index.php",
            "runtimeExecutable": "php",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dzend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so",
                "-S",
                "0.0.0.0:9090"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9090,
            "log" : true
        }
    ]
  }
```

Output from VSCode log:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }

<- outputEvent
OutputEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body:
   { category: 'stderr',
     output:
      '[Fri Nov  1 10:50:06 2019] 127.0.0.1:49922 Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)\n' } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrasing, but i was executing the iDE with CTROL + F5, instead of just F5 (I was used to visual studio).

That was the entire problem...

Thanks!